# Things to keep in mind while extending core java class

Tags: java, oop, filewriter

I have a requirement where I need to extend the FileWriter java class so that I can override the "Write" method to do additional task of creating a copy of the file being modified.
Here is my code:

```
public class MyFileWriter extends FileWriter {
   String fileName;

    public MyFileWriter(String file) throws IOException{
        super(file + ".tmp");
        this.fileName = file;
    }

    public MyFileWriter(File file, boolean append) throws IOException{
        super(File.createTempFile(file.getName(), "tmp") , append);
        this.fileName = file.getAbsolutePath();
    }

    public void write(String str, int off, int len) throws IOException {
        successBackupFile(this.fileName,this.backupFilePath);
        super.write(str, off, len);
        new File(this.fileName+ ".tmp").renameTo(new File(this.fileName));

    }

    private static void successBackupFile(String fileToBackup,String backupFilePath) {

        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd.HH.mm.ss").format(new Date());
        File f = new File(backupFilePath+ timeStamp);

        try
        {
            Files.copy(new File(fileToBackup).toPath(), f.toPath());
        }
        catch(IOException ioe){
           //message
        }
    }

}
```

Q: In my code I am going to use only 2 of the constructor's of FileWriter class, Will it be a good practice to provide definition for all the 4 constructors.
Q: In general, what are the good practices or things to keep in mind while extending native core java class

If anyone can point me to any good reads about things to keep in mind while extending native core java class it will be very helpful.

Comment: "In general, what are the good practices or things to keep in mind while extending native core java class" in general, don't, unless they are specifically designed for inheritance. Provide custom implementations of interfaces, and use composition, rather than inheritance, to reuse the behaviour of core classes.

Comment: What about all the other methods? And why would you do the file renaming after each `write`? Maybe on close would be better

Comment: Also never ignore Exceptions `catch(Exception e){

        }`

Comment: @ScaryWombat... That is just a POC code that I am trying to do. I would never do that is production code.

Comment: "unless they are specifically designed for inheritance" the lack of `final` on a class should not be interpreted that the class is designed for inheritance. Many old classes are non-final because they were designed prior to realising the importance of making them final where possible; and they cannot now be changed without breaking backward compatibility.

Comment: A `FileWriter`'s responsibility is to write character data to a file. It's pretty much the wrong place to make a secret backup.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Inheriting the FileWriter class. You can use compostion.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

public class MyFileWriter {
    private String fileName;
    private String backupFilePath;
    private FileWriter fw;
    
    public MyFileWriter(String file, String backupFilePath) throws IOException{
        fw = new FileWriter(file);
        this.fileName = file;
        this.backupFilePath = backupFilePath;
    }

    public MyFileWriter(File file, boolean append, String backupFilePath) throws IOException{
        this.fw = new FileWriter(file, append);
        this.fileName = file.getName();
        this.backupFilePath = backupFilePath;
    }

    public void write(String str, int off, int len) throws IOException {
        successBackupFile(this.fileName,this.backupFilePath);
        try {
        this.fw.write(str, off, len);}
        catch(IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        finally {
            fw.close();
        }

    }

    private static void successBackupFile(String fileToBackup,String backupFilePath) {
        
        String timeStamp = fileToBackup+"_"+ new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd.HH.mm.ss").format(new java.util.Date());

        File f = new File(backupFilePath+"\\"+ timeStamp);
        try
        {
            Files.copy(new File(fileToBackup).toPath(), f.toPath());
        }
        catch(IOException ioe){
           System.out.println(ioe);
        }

    }
}
```